# IBM Worklight 6.2 show worklightSetting for Native Apps

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

With IBM Worklight 6.2.0.1

Is It possible to show worklightSetting (show/modify worklight server url:port) for Native Apps ?

application-descriptor.xml don't include worklightSetting properties for Native API.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worklightSetting bundle in iOS is available out-of-the-box only for a Hybrid application.
For fully-native applications only an SDK containing adapter and authentication API methods is provided, and so any bundle you'd like to have you will need to implement on your own.

However, starting MobileFirst Platform 6.3, there are new API methods to accomplish exactly this (which you could create a UI for).

- Hybrid: `WL.App.getServerUrl` and `WL.App.setServerUrl`
- Native iOS: `serverUrl` and `setServerUrl` in the [WLClient class](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refobjc-worklight-ios/html/interface_w_l_client.html?cp=SSHS8R_6.3.0%2F9-0-1-1-0-2&lang=en)
- Native Android: `setServerUrl` and `getServerUrl` in the [WL](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjava-worklight-android-native/html/com/worklight/androidgap/api/WL.html?lang=en) and [WLClient](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjava-worklight-android-native/html/com/worklight/wlclient/api/WLClient.html?lang=en) classes
- Native WP8: `WLClient.getInstance().getServerUrl` and `WLClient.getInstance().setServerUrl` in the [WLClient class](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/docs/v630/wl_csharpref_wp8.pdf)